# Polymer 1.0 does not work with Firefox Stable or Developer Edition

Tags: firefox, ruby-on-rails-4, polymer, web-component

Loading the JS file "webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js" helps polymer work on chrome but not in firefox.

I tried adding the following to my application.js file (rails).

`// = require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents`

also tried

`// = require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min`

also tried

`// = require webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min`

using in combination with following JS files.

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery.min
//= require select2/select2
//= require angular/angular.min
//= require fastclick/lib/fastclick
//= require magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min
```

I'm installing all packages from bower and using in rails 4.

Chrome works fine without webcomponentsjs. But when I add webcomponentsjs, chrome stops showing polymer elements and firefox also does not display elements in addition to constantly sending requests to my local server.

Any idea on how to get 1.0 working on firefox? 0.5 was working just fine.

specifically this code does not render:

`<paper-input id="bodyinput" name="thetext" type="text" class="searchbar" placeholder="Enter a search term here..." autofocus>
</paper-input>`

I'm making sure to do the following HTML Imports:

```
<!-- polymer imports -->
<link rel="import" href="/assets/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/assets/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Do you have any code examples or any errors being produced?

Comment: these are the warnings in firefox console- 

```"[paper-dialog::_flattenBehaviorsList]:" "behavior is null, check for missing or 404 import"```

```"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."```

Comment: specifically, I'm having problems with paper-input (thats one of the elements used in my app)

Comment: Are you using the new v1.0 components from here? Are you using angularjs? I've added a paper-dialog to my app and tried in Firefox v38 and it works as expected.

Comment: yes. using v1.0 and angularjs as well.

Comment: This is definitely the first I've heard of it not working with Firefox (though, to be fair, me not hearing about something doesn't mean much). Would you mind posting some code so that there'd be more information to go on? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using  Polymer 0.8+, you have to import webcomponents-lite.js or webcomponents-lite.min.js. After that check in browser, is it receive this file when loading page. Don't forget to check data in received webcomponents file, it can be empty.

The issue with empty webcomponents-lite.js file can appear if you are using some automation tools to build project, like uglify or something else which convert js files into min.js files or made some optimization with imported js files. Just exclude webcomponents-lite.js file from this tasks if they exist.